# confused with call-by-reference in C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

This function does not return the intended result (swapping `a` and `b`).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void swap_one(int *x, int *y) {
    int *tmp;
    tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", *x, *y);
}

void swap_two(int *x, int *y) {

}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 100;
    printf("Before a = %d b = %d\n\n", a, b);
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *q = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    p = &a;
    q = &b;

    swap_one(p, q);
    printf("After a = %d b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

But the below code works as expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct ListElmt_ {
    void *data;
    struct ListElmt_ *next;
} ListElmt;

typedef struct List_ {
    int size;
    int (*match) (const void *key1, const void *key2);
    void (*destroy) (void *data);
    ListElmt *head;
    ListElmt *tail;
} List;

void list_init (List *list) {
    list->size = 0;
    list->match = NULL;
    list->destroy = NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}

int list_ins_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void *data) {
    ListElmt *new_element;
    /* Alocate storage for the element. */
    if ((new_element = (ListElmt *) malloc(sizeof(ListElmt))) == NULL) return -1;
    /* new_element->data is of type void *. So we use (void *) data */
    new_element->data = (void *)data;
    if (element == NULL) {
        /* Handle insertion at the head of the list */
        if (list->size == 0) list->tail = new_element;
        new_element->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_element;
    } else {
        if (element->next == NULL) list->tail = new_element;
        new_element->next = element->next;
        element->next = new_element;
    }
    list->size++;
    return 0;
}

/* Print the list */
static void print_list(const List *list) {
    ListElmt *element;
    int *data;
    int i;
    /* Display the linked list */
    fprintf(stdout, "List size is %d\n", list->size);
    i = 0;
    element = list->head;
    while (1) {
        data = element->data;
        fprintf(stdout, "list[%03d] = %03d\n", i, *data);
        i++;
        if (element->next == NULL) {
            break;
        } else {
            element  = element->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    List list;
    ListElmt *element;
    int *data;
    int i;
    /* list = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)); */
    /* Initialize the linked list */
    List *listPtr;
    listPtr = &list;
    list_init(listPtr);
    /* Perform some linked list operations */
    element = listPtr->head;
    for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        if ( (data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) return 1;
        *data = i;
        if (list_ins_next(listPtr, NULL, data) != 0) return 1;
    }
    print_list(listPtr);
    fprintf(stdout, "Value in *data is:%d\n", *data);
    return 0;
}
```

Question is: In the `swap_one` function, `x=y` is similar to `new_element->next = element->next` or `element->next = new_element`. Why do `new_element->next = element->next` and `element->next = new_element` work but `x =y` in the swap_one function does not swap `a` and `b`?

Sorry for lot of the code but I am genuinely confused about this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The *pointers* are passed *by value*.  Swapping the pointer values held in those variables does not achieve a swap of the data they point to.

1. Imagine that `&p` is the address 0x1000 and `&q` is the address 0x1004.
2. Now, you call `swap_one(&p, &q);` -- the value of the pointer `x` is 0x1000 and the value of the pointer `y` is 0x1004.
3. You now swap the pointer values.  `x` is now 0x1004 which points at `q` and `y` is now 0x1000 which points at `p`.  However, `p` and `q` never moved in memory.  You only changed the values stored in your pointers.
4. When the function returns, those pointers go out of scope.  `p` and `q` still hold the same contents as before, because you never modified them in the first place.

So, to swap the values they point at, you must *dereference* the pointer to get at the actual data.

```
int tmp = *x;
*x = *y;
*y = tmp;
```

Contrast this to your linked list example.  In that example, you had a pointer to a structure, and you were modifying its `next` member.  This *actually* modifies the pointer in memory, because that's where your linked list resides and how it stores values.

However, the same issue would occur if you gave these pointers to some hypothetical function: `swap_next(node **x, node **y);` -- `x` and `y` are just local variables pointing at a pointer value.  If you swap them, they do not modify anything other than themselves.  So the same fix applies: to change data being pointed at, you must follow the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `swap_one` function is only swapping the pointer *values* passed to the function, not what the pointers are pointing to.  So any change you make won't be reflected outside of the function.

You need to dereference those pointers to read/write what they point to.

```
void swap_one(int *x, int *y) {
    int tmp;
    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", *x, *y);
}
```

In the `list_ins_next` function, you are changing what the pointers point to, so the changes are seen outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` and `y` are local variable of `swap_one()`.
This is what happening when you calling `swap_one()` function:

```
p = &a;
q = &b;

p (pointer)        q (pointer)
---                ---
| |---+            | |---+
---   |            ---   |
      |                  |
   a ----             b ----
     |  |               |  |
     ----               ----
```

Calling `swap_one(p, q)` function from `main()` function:

```
p (pointer)        q (pointer)
---                ---
| |---+            | |---+
---   |            ---   |
      |                  |
   a ----             b ----
     |  |               |  |
     ----               ----
      |                  |
      |                  |
---   |            ---   |
| |---+            | |---+
---                ---   
x (pointer)        y (pointer)
pointing to a      pointing to b

(x and y are parameters of swap_one())
```

After execution of these statements of `swap_one()` function:

```
tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

the pointer `x` will point to address that pointer `y` was pointing at and pointer `y` will point to address that pointer `x` was pointing at when `swap_one()` was called.

```
 p (pointer)        q (pointer)
---                ---
| |---+            | |---+
---   |            ---   |
      |                  |
   a ----             b ----
     |  | -----+        |  |
     ----      |        ----
               |         | 
      +--------|---------+
---   |        |   ---   
| |---+        +---| |
---                ---   
x (pointer)        y (pointer)
pointing to b      pointing to a
```

Note that pointer `p` and pointer `q` are still pointing to variable `a` and `b` respectively. That's why when `swap_one()` function returned, the value of variable `a` and `b` is not swapped.

If you want to swap the value of the variables, whose address passed as arguments to `swap_one()` function than dereference the pointer parameters and replace the value at the location, i.e. you should do following in `swap_one()` function:

```
    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y; 
    *y = tmp;
```

With these changes the values of variable whose address passed to `swap_one()` function will be swapped because, now, you are dereferencing the pointer `x` (i.e. `*x`) and pointer `y` (i.e. `*y`) and assigning the values at that location.

Now, coming to this part of second code. Taking the case when `element` is not `NULL`

```
    } else {
    if (element->next == NULL) list->tail = new_element;
    new_element->next = element->next;
    element->next = new_element;
```

Note that `element` pointer is of type `ListElmt` and yes it is also a local pointer variable of `list_ins_next()` function. But, here we are making use of this local pointer variable to modify the value of structure member which it is pointing to.

```
    new_element (pointer of type ListElmt)
      ----
      |  |-----+
      ----     |
               |
           -----------
           |    |    |
           -----------
             ^      ^
             |      |
          data     next
          pointer  pointer


    element (pointer of type ListElmt, which is pointing to an existing node of list
      ----   passed to list_ins_next() function)
      |  |-----+
      ----     |
               |
           -----------
           |    |    |
           -----------
             ^      ^
             |      |
          data     next
          pointer  pointer
```

Note that this

```
new_element->next
```

is same as

```
(*new_element).next
```

which means, dereferencing the `new_element` pointer (go to the location where it is pointing to) and access the `next` pointer at that location.

So, this

```
new_element->next = element->next;
```

will make the `new_element->next` pointer pointing to what `element->next` pointer is pointing and this

```
element->next = new_element; // same as (*element).next = new_element;
```

will make the `element->next` pointer pointing to what `new_element` pointer is pointing at. After execution of these statements,

```
        new_element (pointer of type ListElmt)
      ----
      |  |-----+
      ----     |
               |
           -----------
      +--- |    |    |-------> (pointing to what element->next was pointing at)
      |    -----------
      |      ^      ^
      |      |      |
      |   data     next
      |   pointer  pointer
      --------------------+
                          |
    element               |
      |  |-----+          |
      ----     |          |
               |          |
           -----------    |
           |    |    |----+
           -----------
             ^      ^
             |      |
          data     next
          pointer  pointer
```

So, if you want to make changes in the pointer that you are passing to a function, you have to dereference it in the calling function.

---

If you are still confused then only check this:

In your second code if you do same as what you are doing in first code:

```
example = <some pointer of type ListElmt>;
```

i.e. assign some other pointer of same type to `example`, this is what will happen:

```
     element 
      ----                 -----------
      |  |---------------> |    |    |
      ----                 -----------

         (The original ListElmt type element
          whose address passed to list_ins_next() function)
           -----------
           |    |    |
           -----------
             ^      ^
             |      |
          data     next
          pointer  pointer
```

Now, when `list_ins_next()` function will returned, the original element whose address was passed to this function will remain unchanged.

---

**Additional:**

Here, your program is leaking memory:

```
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *q = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    p = &a;
    q = &b;
```

because the allocated memory references, to pointer `p` and `q`, (using `malloc()`) will be lost when you are assigning `&a` and `&b` to `p` and `q` respectively.